# How to create a drop down menu that links to a specific part of the page?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Okay, so I know how to create a drop down menu. And I know how to create a href that links to a specific part of the page using #. But what I need is a drop down menu that uses those # anchors to direct you to a specific part of the page. So you would click on the drop down, select your option and then it would automatically scroll you down to the appropriate section of the page. Everything I try just isn't working. Any help please?

Here is what I've tried:

```
     <form>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Select Your Location</legend>
      <p>
         <select id = "myList">
           <option value = "#ReigateEvents">Reigate</option>
           <option value = "#GodalmingEvents">Godalming</option>
           <option value = "#Enquiry">I don't see my location here</option>
         </select>
      </p>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: show us what you've tried (tip: use the embedded html/js engine)

Comment: @Edwin I've added what I've got at the moment

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add #after the link.

Try something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/page.html#part1">Part 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/page.html#part2">Part 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/page2.html#part2">Page 2 Part 1</a></li>
```

**Edited**

```
<select id = "myList" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
<option value = "page.html#ReigateEvents">Reigate</option>
<option value = "page.html#GodalmingEvents">Godalming</option>
<option value = "page.html#Enquiry">I don't see my location here</option>
```

Comment: That's not a drop down though is it? That's just a normal list.

Comment: OK. You need a Select option. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with javascript.

```js
function myAnchor(value){
  var top = document.getElementById(value).offsetTop;
  window.scrollTo(0, top);
 //document.getElementById(value).scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
p{
    height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<select id = "myList" onchange="myAnchor(this.value)">
  <option value ="test">Reigate</option>
  <option value ="GodalmingEvents">Godalming</option>
  <option value ="Enquiry">I don't see my location here</option>
</select>

<h2 id="GodalmingEvents">
  GodalmingEvents
</h2>
<h2 id="Enquiry">
  Enquiry
</h2>
<p></p>
<h1 id="test">
  test
</h1>
```